# Making a guessing game in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make a discord bot which starts a game when `!play` message is sent. In the game there is a variable whose value is chosen randomly and if you predict the right number (between 1 and 10) then a `"You win"` message will be sent and if the it is greater or less then a message will be sent accordingly. I know I am messing it because I am using discord.py for the first time.
My code:

```
    if message.content.startswith("!play"):
        await message.channel.send("Choose a number between 1-10. Enter numerical values only.")
        num = random.randint(1,10)  
        try:   
            if message.content.startswith(str(num)):
                await message.channel.send("You won.")
            elif int(message.content) > num:
                await message.channel.send("Go a bit lower.")
            elif int(message.content) < num:
                await message.channel.send("Go a bit up.")
        except Exception as e:
            await message.channel.send("Check inputs.")
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```py
# imports the discord module and the random module.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = discord.Client()


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
Token = "" #your token


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!play"): #the play command to start the guessing game.
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("Choose a number between 1-10. Enter numerical values only.") #message that tells about the start of the game

        # generates a random number and turns it into a string
        number1 = random.randint(1,10)        
        number2 = str(number1)


        def check(m):
            return m.content == number2 and m.channel == channel 
        """
          The check function, first it checks if the message is the correct number.
          Then it checks if the channel is the same channel as the channel that the play command was sent in.
          If both is true, then it returns true. Else it returns false.
        """
        
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) #waits for the check function to return true
        await channel.send("Correct answer {.author}" .format(msg)) #sends the correct answer message
        
client.run(Token)
```

This should work.
I have a working bot here: https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=793152585346711573&permissions=8&scope=bot 
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou60F.png

Comment: Your solution is working! Thank you very much. It would be extremely good of you if you would explain how does it work like a bit of an explanation I am very new to this discord api.

Comment: I added explanations.